# Error when I open a workbook (we found a problem with some content in"workbook name", do you want us to try to recover as much as we can) again

Tags: excel, vba, validation

i had the above error before and it was due to xlValidatelist limited to 256 characters, solved by saving the validation list value into a cell in the sheet then doing the validation internally, i got this error back again eventhough im doing the same solution, the code im using is below:

```
Sub validatesepcode()
Call establish_conn
Call open_conn
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim valList As String
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Installation Price")
Set rng = ws.Range("A32:A38")
Set rng2 = ws.Range("A73")
If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
valList = ""
rs.Open "SELECT [Model] FROM tblData WHERE [Brand] = '" & Sheets("General").Cells(7, 4).Value & "' AND [Description2] = 'Separation';", conn
Do While Not rs.EOF
        
        valList = valList & rs.Fields("Model").Value & ","
        rs.MoveNext
Loop
If Len(valList) > 0 Then
    
                valList = Left(valList, Len(valList) - 1)
                ws.Range("A73").Value = valList
                
                With rng.Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=rng2
                End With
End If


End Sub
```

the error disappears when i isolate this code from the worksheet activate condition as below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.EnableEvents = True
'Call validatesepcode
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A32:A38")) Is Nothing Then
     Call bringsepdata2
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

what could be the problem in this case?

Comment: Reboot your computer, possibly more than once!

Comment: You're repeating the same problem as previously, only you're loading the list string from a cell instead of from a VBA variable.  It still triggers the same error.  You need to assign the lookup list to a column of cells, one value per cell, not to a single cell as a comma-delimited list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to point a validation list to a range, it should look more like this:

```vb
'...
Set rng2 = ws.Range("A73")
'...
rs.Open "SELECT [Model] FROM tblData WHERE [Brand] = '" & _
        Sheets("General").Cells(7, 4).Value & _
        "' AND [Description2] = 'Separation';", conn

If Not rs.EOF Then 'any records returned?
    rng2.Resize(1000).ClearContents 'remove any previous list values
    rng2.CopyFromRecordset rs       'populate the recordset to the worksheet
    Set rng2 = ws.Range(rng2, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, rng2.Column).End(xlUp)) 'list range
    
    With rng.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
             Formula1:="='" & ws.Name & "'!" & rng2.Address(False, False)
    End With
Loop
```

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question; this will help anyone coming along later with a similar problem.